# Running a node.js script in Docker

Tags: node.js, bash, docker

I have a node.js script that when it's executed it just run a process to copy two tables from one database to another one. If I run it in my local it works as it should, so there is no coding issue.
My problem is, I want to put that node.js program inside a docker image and execute that image (and the node.js script) when I needed. I created the image but when I run it just say that was executed x amount of time ago, but it doesn't do what the script does.

Can anyone explain me what I can do to accomplish this?

Steps are:

- I need to pass an optional parameter to npm like: `npm start Initial`.
- I need to be able to do the same inside the container:.

I have a *file.sh* that do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 = "Initial" ]; then
    : npm start $1
else
    : npm start
fi
```

But again, when I run the docker with something like this :

```
docker run [image-name] Initial
```

It doesn't give me any error but is not executing my node.js script. My Dockerfile is something like this:

```
...
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/file.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/file.sh"]
```

Comment: Does your image build? Where did you get that syntax for the RUN command? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not share the base image, but one issue might be that the base image is base on alpine so `#!/bin/bash` this will not work, plus you need variable expansion with proper to avoid error on empty.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "${1}" = "Initial" ]; then
    npm start "${1}"
else
    npm start
fi
```

Here is the working example that you can try

```
git clone https://github.com/Adiii717/docker-npm-argument.git
cd docker-npm-argument;
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

or to pass argument

```
docker-compose run docker-npm-argument argument1 arguments
```

To check same with docker run command

```
docker run --rm docker-npm-argument "Initial"
```

output

```
Args passed to docker run command are [ initial ]
starting application

> app@0.0.0 start /app
> node app.js "initial"

Node process arguments [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/app/app.js', 'initial' ]
```